# How to change the numbers in steps of material-ui Stepper?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stepper

[image]

These steps takes the numbers which are length of the **steps** array i.e

```
    state = {
       steps: [0, 1, 2, 3]
    };
```

Later this state may change to

```
    this.setState({
      steps: [1,2,3,4]
    });
```

Or

```
   this.setState({
     steps: [2,3,4,5]
   });
```

and so on....

But in all the cases my steps show only 1,2,3,4,. I need to change those numbers according to the steps' array element.

This is the code for stepper.

```
<Stepper alternativeLabel nonLinear activeStep={activePage}>
     {steps.map((step, index) => {
       return (
        <Step key={index}>
          <StepButton
            onClick={this.handleStep(index)}
            disabled={dealsLoading}
          >
            </StepButton>
        </Step>
      );
    })}
  </Stepper>
```

How to achieve that?

If I use StepLabel component it looks like
[image]

But I don't want label. I want those labels should be on step buttons.
Code for this:

```
 <Stepper alternativeLabel nonLinear activeStep={activePage}>
        {steps.map((step, index) => {
          return (
            <Step key={index}>
               <StepLabel 
                  onClick={this.handleStep(step)}
                  disabled={dealsLoading}
               >
                {step}
              </StepLabel>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your question what I understood is your `steps` numbers are changes right? If so then
**Problem**: Basically you are changing your step number but sending index.

```
{steps.map((step, index) => {
       return (
        <Step key={index}>
          <StepButton
            onClick={this.handleStep(step)} // passed step value instead of index.
            disabled={dealsLoading}
          >
            </StepButton>
        </Step>
      );
    })}
```

If this is not scenarios please edit and elaborate your with example like `step array` on click of step `acitveindex` value you wish. Please show code of function `handleStep`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Initially step state contains [0,1,2,3 ] only. still the step buttons show 1,2,3,4.  If I change initial state of steps to [1,2,5,6] (some random) also, step buttons are still 1,2,3,4.  Why don't they change?

Comment: Use `StepLabel` component pass label as children to it, read docs, will edit ans

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12262   :  finally this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Was dealing with this myself, due to having unlabeled steps and not wanting the total number to change. What you need to do is provide `icon={step}` to your StepLabel.

```
<Stepper alternativeLabel nonLinear activeStep={activePage}>
  {steps.map((step, index) => (
    <Step key={index}>
      <StepLabel
        onClick={this.handleStep(step)}
        disabled={dealsLoading}
        icon={step}
      >
        {step}
      </StepLabel>
    </Step>
  ))}
</Stepper>
```

This worked perfectly for me, hope you can use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to @Shadoath where I needed the icons to display from step 0 up to number of steps-1:

```
<Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel sx={{ mt: 2 }}> 
   {steps.map((step, idx) => 
       <Step key={idx}>
           <StepLabel icon={`${idx}`}>{step.label}</StepLabel>
        </Step>
    )}
</Stepper>
```